# Selenium выдает ошибку, но убрав options = options она пропадает

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()

options.add_argument('user-data-dir=путь')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='путь', chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://google.com')


Error
:\Users\brodi\Desktop\бот.py:13: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\brodi\\Desktop\\bots\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brodi\Desktop\бот.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\brodi\\Desktop\\bots\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
  File "C:\Users\brodi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\brodi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\brodi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 266, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\brodi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 357, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\brodi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\brodi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x009E6903+2517251]
    Ordinal0 [0x0097F8E1+2095329]
    Ordinal0 [0x00882848+1058888]
    Ordinal0 [0x0089D8AB+1169579]
    Ordinal0 [0x0089A2CF+1155791]
    Ordinal0 [0x008CAAAF+1354415]
    Ordinal0 [0x008CA71A+1353498]
    Ordinal0 [0x008C639B+1336219]
    Ordinal0 [0x008A27A7+1189799]
    Ordinal0 [0x008A3609+1193481]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B75904+1577972]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C20B97+2279047]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A76D09+534521]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A75DB9+530601]
    Ordinal0 [0x00984FF9+2117625]
    Ordinal0 [0x009898A8+2136232]
    Ordinal0 [0x009899E2+2136546]
    Ordinal0 [0x00993541+2176321]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x773B6359+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77708964+228]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77708934+180]
```

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

> `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='путь', chrome_options=options)`

Согласно документации [Chrome WebDriver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver), параметр `chrome_options` устаревший:

> chrome_options - Deprecated argument for options

Вместо него используйте `options`:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='путь', options=options)
```

Comment: я уже использовал и options и chrome_options

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки при использовании параметра `options=`